# Map <number><cr> to go to the line

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I have the following line in my config:

```
map <cr> G
```

So I can type `123<cr>` and go to the line 123, but I don't really want to go to the end of file if I did not type any numbers. How do I map it so it only works with numbers typed ahead?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want `<CR>` with no count to behave the same as `<CR>` with no mapping?

Comment: I the case it's just about the end of the file, you also have `gg` which will move you to the beginning of the file without any count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an expression mapping. From `:h <expr>`

```
                        *:map-<expr>* *:map-expression*
If the first argument to one of these commands is "<expr>" and it is used to
define a new mapping or abbreviation, the argument is an expression.  The
expression is evaluated to obtain the {rhs} that is used.  Example: >
    :inoremap <expr> . InsertDot()
The result of the InsertDot() function will be inserted.  It could check the
text before the cursor and start omni completion when some condition is met.
```

So the mapping you are looking for is

```
nnoremap <expr> <cr> v:count == 0 ? "\<cr>" : "G"
```